# Access Mysql server using socks proxy from a php script

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [mysql proxy socks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874556/mysql-proxy-socks)

I need to access a mysql server using socks proxy from a php script. Please could anyone help me to do this.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/874556/mysql-proxy-socks