# mysql_connect using proxy

Tags: php, mysql, proxy

Hii,

Is it possible to use `mysql_connect()` behind a proxy server. I am trying to connect to an external db, which basically is on my hosting servers. I am behind my university proxy.

Comment: Are you also sure that your hosting provider allows remote mysql connections?  As far as I recall, that's uncommon.

Comment: Do you know which port-ranges are available to you via the proxy and can you say if remote connections of your webhost for mysql are accepted?

Comment: yes it allows. Previously I used to work from home and everything was fine. I came to college as my vacation was over. my proxy is localhost:8888

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FWIK and according to the answer in [mysql proxy socks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874556/mysql-proxy-socks), mysql does not offer support to connect via proxies. See the linked answer how you can go around this.