# php eloquent mysql connect through proxy

Tags: php, eloquent

I have a MySQL DB and two servers.

I currently connect to the DB directly from Server 1.
I would like to connect to the DB through Server 2 instead so that the DB does not know the exact source of the request. Is there some way to tell php/eloquent to connect through the second server?

Comment: What do you mean by "through server 2" are server 1 and 2 proxies? Why do you want to connect through server 2, what problem do you want to solve?

Comment: @ErikKalkoken both are my own machines. I would like to use server 2 as a proxy that eloquent can connect through.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql proxy socks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874556/mysql-proxy-socks)